# I have a problem copying files in bash from subdirectories to parent directories

Tags: bash, macos, shell, terminal, permissions

**Hello everyone**

I have a bash script to install my bash based application (they are just bash scripts that I wrapped to work as an application with [Platypus](https://sveinbjorn.org/platypus).

I have my applications that I need to copy to the parent directory in the resources folder of the "installing application".

It goes something like this:

```
AFolderWhereItGotDownloaded/
   Install.app/
      Contents/
         MacOS/
         Info.plist
         Resources/
            Application1.app/ <-- This is the application that I want to move to "AFolderItGotDownloaded"
            Application2.app/ <-- This is the application that I want to move to "AFolderItGotDownloaded"
            AppSettings.plist
            AppIcon.icns
            MainMenu.nib
            script <-- This is the script that runs when I double click the app
```

The only thing I want to do is `cp -r` or `rsync -r` the two applications to `AFolderWhereItGotDownloaded/`

**What I've done so far:**

```
#!/bin/bash

#The directory of the script
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" &>/dev/null 2>&1 && pwd )"

#The "parent" directory
PARENTDIR="../../.."

cp -r "${DIR}/Application1.app" "${PARENTDIR}/Application1.app"
cp -r "${DIR}/Application2.app" "${PARENTDIR}/Application2.app"
```

*What I get:*

```
cp: ../../../Application1.app: Permission denied
cp: ~/Downloads/AFolderWhereItGotDownloaded/Install.app/Contents/Resources/Application1.app: unable to copy extended attributes to ../../../Application1.app: Permission denied
```

**With rsync**

```
#!/bin/bash

#The directory of the script
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" &>/dev/null 2>&1 && pwd )"

#The "parent" directory
PARENTDIR="../../.."

rsync -r "${DIR}/Application1.app" "${PARENTDIR}/Application1.app"
rsync -r "${DIR}/Application2.app" "${PARENTDIR}/Application2.app"
```

*What I get:*

```
rsync: mkdir "~/../../../Application1.app" failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-52.200.1/rsync/main.c(545) [receiver=2.6.9]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (8 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-52.200.1/rsync/io.c(453) [sender=2.6.9]
```

If someone knows what's going on it would be nice...

> `OS: macOS Mojave (10.14.6)`

The file information window states that I have permissions to read and write the folders.

**Results of `ls -l`**

*Inside AFolderWhereItGotDownloaded*

```
total 16
drwxr-xr-x@ 3 <myusername>  staff    96  4 mai 00:13 Install.app
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 <myusername>  staff  1069 28 avr 13:20 LICENSE.txt
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 <myusername>  staff  2586  3 mai 15:05 README.md
```

*Inside Install.app*

```
total 0
drwxr-xr-x@ 5 <myusername>  staff  160  4 mai 00:13 Contents
```

*Inside Contents*

```
total 8
-rwxr-xr-x@  1 <myusername>  staff  632  3 mai 14:56 Info.plist
drwxr-xr-x@  3 <myusername>  staff   96  4 mai 00:13 MacOS
drwxrwxrwx@ 17 <myusername>  staff  544  4 mai 13:43 Resources
```

*Inside Resources*

```
total 728 (I have other apps too but to keep it clean I only stated two "Applications" here)
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 <myusername>  staff  313202  3 mai 14:54 AppIcon.icns
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 <myusername>  staff     499  3 mai 14:56 AppSettings.plist
drwxrwxrwx@ 3 <myusername>  staff      96  4 mai 00:13 Application1.app
drwxrwxrwx@ 3 <myusername>  staff      96  4 mai 00:13 Application2.app
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 <myusername>  staff   42236  3 mai 14:56 MainMenu.nib
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 <myusername>  staff     940  4 mai 14:29 script
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the problem was that macOS sandboxes applications downloaded from the web: The only way of getting it working is to put the apps into the Applications folder.

Answer (score 1):

`PARENTDIR="../../.."` is wrong. If you execute `cd ~; pwd`, it will show something like `/home/user`. Since this is two deep, you should use `PARENTDIR="../.."` instead.

Also, you have to have root-like privileges (root, sudo) to create files in the root directory. It's better to the software in `/opt` instead and add it to the users `PATH` variable, eg `export PATH=$PATH:/opt/myapp/bin/`. For `/opt` you also need root-like privileges.

Comment: Thank's! That's what I figured out and I'm actually working on a way of having root-like privileges (with sudo) with Platypus